# No logro obtener el contenido de un script

Tags: javascript

No logro obtener el contenido de un script que se encuentra en la misma ruta que el `index.html`. Me interesa obtener unas etiquetas `<h1>` y `<h2>` que se encuentra dentro del archivo `prueba.js`:

**¿Qué puedo hacer?**

```js
var button = document.getElementById("btn");
var caja = document.getElementById("contenido");

// 
var txt = document.getElementById("script");
var result = txt.innerHTML;

button.onclick = function() {
caja.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```html
<script id="script" type="text/html" src="prueba.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Obtener</button>
<div id="contenido"></div>



<!-- ESTO ES LO QUE SE ENCUENTRA DENTRO DE PRUEBA.JS -->
<h1>Texto 1</h1>
<h2>Texto 2</h2>

<!-- ETC... -->
```

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el contenido real del archivo `prueba.js`? Por desgracia no se puede acceder ni modificar el código externo de un script, aunque lo definas como `text/html`. La única forma de obtener su contenido es a través de `XMLHttpRequest` o `fetch()`. ¿Quieres que te ponga un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

No puedes acceder al contenido del script porque en el DOM sólo se ha generado este nodo sin contenido interno (entre el comienzo y el fin de la etiqueta `<script>`):

```
<script id="script" type="text/html" src="prueba.js"></script>
```

Si fuera un script en línea entonces sí que podrías acceder a su contenido, porque forma parte del DOM:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let caja = document.getElementById('contenido');
let txt = document.getElementById('script');

/* Cuando pulsemos el botón cambiamos el contenido de "caja" */
button.addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => caja.innerHTML = txt.innerHTML
);
```

```html
<script id="script" type="text/html">
<h1>Texto 1</h1>
<h2>Texto 2</h2>
</script>

<button id="btn">Obtener</button>
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

De modo que la mejor alternativa para acceder al contenido del archivo es a través de una petición `XMLHttpRequest` o `fetch()`:

```js
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
let caja = document.getElementById('contenido');
let txt = document.getElementById('script');

/* Cuando pulsemos el botón obtenemos el script y lo mostramos en "caja" */
button.addEventListener(
  'click',
  () => fetch(txt.src)
    .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
    .then(html => caja.innerHTML = html)
);
```

```html
<script id="script" type="text/html" src="prueba.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Obtener</button>
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

Dado que el ejemplo anterior no funcionará en esta página porque no se pueden alojar archivos, te he preparado un repositorio en github con todo el código necesario para reproducir el funcionamiento del ejemplo: https://github.com/ojgarciab/331097-stackoverflow-es

[image: Gitpod Ready-to-Code]

---

**Recomendaciones:**

- Debido que existe una incongruencia entre el nombre del archivo (`prueba.js`) y su contenido (HTML), te recomiendo que cambies el nombre y/o extensión (por ejemplo `prueba.html`) para que los tipos mime coincidan. No hacerlo puede crearte confusión a ti y a quien lea el código.
- Ya que vas a cargar el contenido de forma asíncrona, no necesitas declarar el nombre del archivo en una etiqueta `<script>`.